# How to save TextAlignment by NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, textview, nsuserdefaults

My question is how to save a textView's textAlignment by NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

textalignment is an enum so you can save it as an int:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:<#(NSInteger)#> forKey:<#(NSString *)#>]
```

Comment: So I do not should to use NSData??

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:myTextView.textAlignment forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"note%dtextAlignmentData",textNumber]];

something like this???

Comment: no nsdata is too much for your purposes, it is used to encapsulate objects. you only need to save an integer which has built-in support for userdefaults, go for that one.

Comment: yes that looks fine, just be sure that you can compose "note%dtextAlignmentData" later again to retrieve the saved textalignment